# minimizing collisions when storing uuids as integers

Tags: python, base64, backend, encode

So I have a unique situation. I have a bunch of uuids that I am storing right now. I need to convert them into integer values so that my ML algorithm can read it and make calculations. What is the best way to do this while minimizing collisions?

Here is what I am doing right now but I believe it will lead to some collisions:

```
input = "1c7a2bc6-ca2d-47ab-9808-1820241cf4d6"
id = uuid.UUID(input)
print(id.int)
```

What is the best route? I think base64 might be useful but I need it to be in integer format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a dictionary to assign a unique integer to each value of uuid:

```
if uuid not in uuid_dict:
    uuid_dict[uuid] = len(uuid_dict)
```